# using an enum as an object in PerformSelector: WithObject:

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums, selector, typedef

I don't understand some behaviour in my code. I have defined an enum as such at the top of my .m file:

```
typedef NS_ENUM (NSInteger, connectionState) {
tryingToConnect,
connecting,
disconnecting
};
```

Further down my code I call the method:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(animateForState:) withObject:tryingToConnect afterDelay:1.5];
```

This works perfectly fine.

Yet if I call the same with "connecting" or "disconnecting":

```
[self performSelector:@selector(animateForState:) withObject:connecting afterDelay:1.5];
```

Xcode warns me that "Implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC". Why does the top enum variable (tryingToConnect) work and not the following ones (connecting/disconnecting) in my type definition?

For the sake of including everything this is what the method called looks like:

```
- (void)animateForState:(connectionState)state{

    switch (state) {
        case tryingToConnect:{

            NSLog(@"trying to connect");
            break;
        }
        case connecting:{

            NSLog(@"connecting");
            break;
        }

        case disconnecting:{

            NSLog(@"disconnecting");
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works because the value of the first object is 0, which is the same as passing nil. It's ok to pass nil, but not another primitive. Pass the NSNumber instead,  withObject:@(connecting), and switch on state.integerValue

Comment: Aaah I had a knack it had to do with the first value being 0 but hadn't realised it was equivalent to passing nil... Thanks a lot @rdelmar it works fine now!